# Displaying useful contextual information without confusing user

Tags: website-design

So I have this page (See below all text), the page is supposed to show users but organized by what group they are assigned to (Guest, Level 1, Level 2, etc). On this page I also would like it if admins could create new accounts for new users.

What I have currently looks like a mess and there's too much white space and looks horrible to the eye.

What do you suggest I could do to unclutter and make this page look great?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1obU6.jpg]
Link to HD: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1obU6.jpg

Comment: Questions asking for site reviews are typically deemed off-topic; could you rephrase your question to be more specific?

Comment: Lose the background or dim it substantially. I can't see the forest for the trees.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say your main problem is the distracting graphic in the background. It is drawing my eye around the page instead of the actual content. There are some places where it is too light to give a good contrast for reading the text on the page.

Whitespace doesn't have to be filled to a page look good. Whitespace is a tool you can use to make it clear when things are part of a group of functionality and when they are separate (gestalt principles).

Instead of focusing on the whitespace, focus on the content. Think about what your user will want to find quickly and give it more visual weight. Make the page easier to scan by having less distractions. What you have there looks like it would be good without the graphic behind it.